# Is it possible to use a for loop inside a streambuilder?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use a streambuilder to fetch some data from cloud firestore, and return a column using that data, the problem is that when i try plugging a for loop to the builder (as shown on the code block), it prompts me that the builder function returned null, which doesnt happen when I remove the for loop.

The thing is that i need to use a for loop (or similar) to achieve what I need, because I'm using the data on pairs (as shown on the code block), the first container uses data snapshot `i` and the second one uses data snapshot `i+1`. Then for the next iteration `i` will be `2` so a for loop does just fine for this job.

Im also providing you with the stacktrace. Thanks in advance.

```
Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.35,
                        child: StreamBuilder(
                          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('XXXXX').document('XXXXXXXXX').collection('XXXXXX').snapshots(),
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            if(!snapshot.hasData) return 
                            Center(
                              child: Text('No documents to be shown')
                            );
                            final int largoDocumentos = snapshot.data.documents.length;
                            for(var i = 0; i > largoDocumentos; i = i + 2) {
                              return Column(  
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Container(
                                    height: 130,
                                    child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Material(
                                            color: Colors.blueGrey[50],
                                            child: InkWell(
                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28.0),
                                              onTap: () {

                                              },
                                              child: Container(
                                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                                                child: Column(
                                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                  children: <Widget>[
                                                    Text(snapshot.data.documents[i]['XXXXX'].toUpperCase(),
                                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center, 
                                                        style: TextStyle( 
                                                            fontSize: 18,
                                                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                            color: Colors.grey)
                                                        ),
                                                      RadialProgress(0, 65.0, 20.0),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Material(
                                            color: Colors.blueGrey[50],
                                            child: InkWell(
                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28.0),
                                              onTap: () {
                                              },
                                              child: Container(
                                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                                                child: Column(
                                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                  children: <Widget>[
                                                    Text(snapshot.data.documents[i+1]['XXXXX'].toUpperCase(),
                                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center, 
                                                        style: TextStyle( 
                                                            fontSize: 18,
                                                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                            color: Colors.grey)
                                                        ),
                                                      RadialProgress(30, 65.0, 20.0),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 25,),
                                ],
                              );
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
```

```
I/flutter ( 5721): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 5721): The following assertion was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(dirty, state:
I/flutter ( 5721): _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>>#bc925):
I/flutter ( 5721): A build function returned null.
I/flutter ( 5721): The offending widget is: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>
I/flutter ( 5721): Build functions must never return null. To return an empty space that causes the building widget to
I/flutter ( 5721): fill available room, return "new Container()". To return an empty space that takes as little room as
I/flutter ( 5721): possible, return "new Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)".
I/flutter ( 5721):
I/flutter ( 5721): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 5721): #0      debugWidgetBuilderValue.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:270:7)
I/flutter ( 5721): #1      debugWidgetBuilderValue (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:287:4)
I/flutter ( 5721): #2      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3742:7)
I/flutter ( 5721): #3      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3564:5)
I/flutter ( 5721): #4      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2277:33)
I/flutter ( 5721): #5      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:700:20)
I/flutter ( 5721): #6      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:275:5)
I/flutter ( 5721): #7      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:990:15)
I/flutter ( 5721): #8      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:930:9)
I/flutter ( 5721): #9      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:842:5)
I/flutter ( 5721): #13     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:209:10)
I/flutter ( 5721): #14     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:168:3)
I/flutter ( 5721): (elided 3 frames from package dart:async)
I/flutter ( 5721): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: Sorry my comment was wrong and I deleted it. Can you try to populate a list of widgeds with that for loop then return that list? It might solve your problem. Can't test it at the moment.

Comment: @easeccy How can i populate a list of widgets?

Comment: Careate a list of widget (ex. List<Widget> _myList= [])  then try to add widgets to it in for loop (ex. _myList.add(widget)). Then return _myList. I can help in realtime if you write your problem at https://gitter.im/flutter/flutter.

Comment: @easeccy didn't work either, it seems like the for loop isnt adding any widget to the list.

Comment: First get the snaphot from StreamBuilder. Then fill a list with your widgets. Use Listview.builder to show that list on UI as in this example https://flutterbyexample.com/list-view-and-builder-methods

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the snapshot is empty in the first place, hence why it throws a `null` error.

It's also fine to implement a for-loop in a StreamBuilder. If you don't need to track the index, you can use a `forEach` loop.

```dart
if(snapshot.hasData){
  snapshot.data.documents.forEach((document){
    // List documents can be accessed here
  });
} else {
  // Display progressBar
}
```